# access property of type parameter object

Tags: c#

I am using the below code

```
 public static void SaveArrayAsCSV<T>(T[] arrayToSave, string fileName)
        {
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                foreach (T item in arrayToSave)
                {
                    //item.GetType().GetField("AccountName")
                    //item.GetType().GetProperty("AccountName")
                    file.WriteLine(item + ",");
                }
            }
        }
```

Here the item has property called `AccountName`,

I tried to access it using

```
item.GetType().GetField("AccountName") //returns null
item.GetType().GetProperty("AccountName") //returns an  object, not able to spot the actual value in it
```

But both are not returning the values. But when I check using the quick watch I am able to see the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `GetValue` method, try this:

```
var accountName = item.GetType().GetProperty("AccountName").GetValue(item);
```